# T-sql: calculate sum of factors when quantity of factors can differ from time to time

Tags: sql, t-sql, logic, sql-server-2017

Would you please, help me, to develop the algorythm of counting rating of the clients.
Initial dataset and desirable result is in the code below. Thank you.

The logic:
We have clients and 6 factors (with values 1 or 0 (present or not present)).

We should calculate a rating of the client:

1 (max rate) - client has all the factors

2 - client has factors 1-5 and doesn't have 6th

3 - client has factors 1-4 and doesn't have 5th (factor 6 doesn't matter)

4 - client has factors 1-3 and doesn't have 4th (factors 5-6 don't matter)

5 - client has factors 1-2 and doesn't have 3rd (factors 4-6 don't matter)

6 - client has factor 1 and doesn't have 2nd (factors 3-6 don't matter)

7 - client doesnt have factor 1 (factors 2-6 don't matter)

The key is that number of factors can differ from time to time.

```
drop table if exists #tmp;

create TABLE #tmp (
[client] [nvarchar] null,
    [factor1] [int] NULL,
    [factor2] [int] NULL,
    [factor3] [int] NULL,
    [factor4] [int] NULL,
    [factor5] [int] NULL,
    [factor6] [int] null,
    [desirable_result] [int] NULL
) 

insert into #tmp (
[client]
    ,[factor1]
    ,[factor2]
    ,[factor3]
    ,[factor4]
    ,[factor5]
    ,[factor6]
    ,[desirable_result]
)
select '1', 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 union all
select '2', 1,1,0,1,1,1,5 union all
select '3', 1,0,1,1,0,1,6 union all
select '4', 1,1,1,1,1,0,2 union all
select '5', 1,1,1,0,0,1,4
```

This solution works, but only if the num of factors is always equal.
The key is that number of factors can differ from time to time.

```
select *
, "factor1" + "factor2" + "factor3" + "factor4" + "factor5" + "factor6" sum_6
, "factor1" + "factor2" + "factor3" + "factor4" + "factor5" sum_5
, "factor1" + "factor2" + "factor3" + "factor4" sum_4
, "factor1" + "factor2" + "factor3" sum_3
, "factor1" + "factor2" sum_2
, "factor1" sum_1
into #tmp2
from #tmp

select * 
, case when sum_6 = 6 then 1 else 
(case when sum_5 = 5 and sum_6 < 6 then 2 else 
(case when sum_4 = 4 and sum_5 < 5 then 3 else 
(case when sum_3 = 3 and sum_4 < 4 then 4 else 
(case when sum_2 = 2 and sum_3 < 3 then 5 else 
(case when sum_1 = 1 and sum_2 < 2 then 6 else 
7
end)
end) 
end) 
end) 
end) 
end rate
from
#tmp2
```

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Squirrel, I'm using SQL Server 2017

Comment: what you want can be done using `CASE` . It will be a bit ugly but it will work

Comment: why is `client 5` with `result = 3` when there is only `factor 1 to 3 with 1`

Comment: Squirrel, thank you for correction and understanging the logic. client 5 should have result = 4. I will correct my post in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CASE WHEN ...` as what scaisEdge has demonstrated.

What i have here is to `UNPIVOT` the table using `CROSS APPLY` and then using `SUM()` with `CASE` to workout the necessary logic

```
select  t.client, 
        t.[desirable_result],
        case    when    sum(f.fval) = 6 then 1
                when    sum(f.fval) = 5 
                and     sum(case when f.fno  = 6 then f.fval end) = 0 then 2
                when    sum(case when f.fno <= 4 then f.fval end) = 4 
                and     sum(case when f.fno  = 5 then f.fval end) = 0 then 3
                when    sum(case when f.fno <= 3 then f.fval end) = 3 
                and     sum(case when f.fno  = 4 then f.fval end) = 0 then 4
                when    sum(case when f.fno <= 2 then f.fval end) = 2 
                and     sum(case when f.fno  = 3 then f.fval end) = 0 then 5
                when    sum(case when f.fno  = 1 then f.fval end) = 1 
                and     sum(case when f.fno  = 2 then f.fval end) = 0 then 6
                when    sum(case when f.fno  = 1 then f.fval end) = 0 then 7
                end
from    #tmp t
        cross apply
        (
            values  
            (1, factor1),
            (2, factor2),
            (3, factor3),
            (4, factor4),
            (5, factor5),
            (6, factor6)
        ) f (fno, fval)
group by t.client, t.[desirable_result]
order by t.client
```

Comment: Squirrel, your code works well and I will use it with pleasure. The only thing left: to make it dynamic. Format of input values is always equal: client and some number of factors with names factor1, factor2, factorN (may be 5, may be 25 factors).

Comment: if you can normalize the `#tmp` table, it will be much easier. That is what the `CROSS APPLY` is doing. It `unpivot` and normalize it

Comment: Squirrel, thank you. I will take some time to learn 'cross apply' function since don't have much experience of using it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CASE WHEN

```
select case 
    when  [factor1] = 1 
        AND [factor2] = 1 
        AND [factor3] = 1 
        AND [factor4] = 1
        AND [factor5] = 1 
        AND [factor6] = 1
    then 'ALL6'
    when  [factor1] = 1 
        AND [factor2] = 1 
        AND [factor3] = 1 
        AND [factor4] = 1
        AND [factor5] = 1 
    then 'FIRST5'
     .....
     ....
    when  [factor1] = 1 
        AND [factor2] = 1 
        AND [factor3] = 1 
        AND [factor4] = 1
    then 'FIRST4'


    when  [factor1] = 1 
    then 'ONLy1'     END client_rate 
from my_table
```

chenge the dot.... with the missing conditions

Comment: scaisEdge - thank you for your solution. It works great if the number of factors is always equal. I have developed your solution and posted it in the topic. But id doesn't work when the number of factors is different from time to time. There would be great to have dynamic SQL.